# Hachoir Parser in Android

Tags: android, python, hachoir-parser

I need to implement the Hachoir framework in the android phone. I am lost as to where to start and how to go about understanding the framework. Is there anyway to call the python files into my android code or some other documentation which will help me get started ? I appreciate the help !

Answer (score 1):

You asked a general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. On android, you can't execute python as far as I know. The only thing that comes close is [Android Scripting Environment](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html).

Comment: Using the ASE is one option but I dont think that's what I want in this case. What I specifically want is to understand the main logic behind the parsers in the Hachoir framework and rewrite the python code in java. But I m lost as to where to start.